# secret sharing of product of 2 numbers

Tags: secret-sharing

Does evaluating the products of shares $a_jb_j$ give a secret sharing of $ab$? 
I think it's a no, but I am not sure on how to prove it.

Comment: What secret sharing technique are you using? Shamir?

Comment: Can be any one @mikeazo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary secret sharing methods in use for multiparty computation today are Shamir's and additive. I'm going to assume that you understand both.

**Additive**
No. When you go to reconstruct, you would have (simplified for 2 parties) $a_1b_1+a_2b_2\neq(a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2)$. To prove it in the general case you would have to extend that analysis to $n$ parties.

**Shamir**
Yes and no. In Shamir's we say that $a_i=p(i)$ for some polynomial $p$ and $b_i=q(i)$ for some polynomial $q$. Now lets assume that $p$ is used to share $s$ (i.e., $p(0)=s$) and $q$ is used to share $t$. It is the case that $a_ib_i=(p*q)(i)$ and $(p*q)(0)=st$. So, $a_ib_i$ is indeed a valid share from some polynomial which evaluates to $st$ at $0$. There are, however, two problems.

1. The polynomial $(p*q)$ does not have random coefficients. The coefficients will depend on each other
2. The degree of the polynomial changes. Lets say that both $p$ and $q$ have degree $r$ (thus it takes $r+1$ shares to reconstruct the secret). The polynomial $(p*q)$ has degree $2r$, so it would take $2r+1$ shares to reconstruct $st$.

For these reasons, MPC protocols which use Shamir have a multiplication protocol which fixes these issues.

**Another possibility**
I don't even know if this is a secure secret sharing method (I'm hoping someone can comment). But you could use multiplicative secret sharing.

Fix a multiplicative group, say $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$.

Let $a_i$ be shares of $s$ such that $s=\displaystyle\prod_i(a_i)$ and similarly $b_i$ are shares of $t$. Then thanks to the commutativity of multiplication $a_ib_i$ would be a multiplicative share of $st$

Comment: So evaluating $a_j+b_j$ gives a secret sharing of $ab$ for Shamir's secret sharing? @mikeazo

Comment: @freak_warrior, no $a_j+b_j$ gives a share of $a+b$, $a_jb_j$ gives a share of $ab$ but with the caveats listed above.

Comment: @freak_warrior, FYI I asked a specific question about the multiplicative version: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11535/is-multiplicative-secret-sharing-secure