# security of multiplicative secret sharing

Tags: secret-sharing

I was having a read of this question: "[Is multiplicative secret sharing secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11535/is-multiplicative-secret-sharing-secure)"
posted in 2013 which asks if the simple multiplicative scheme is secure. 
Everyone agreed that it was information theoretic secure, however I am not so sure that this is the case. In particular, if the secret is 0 then does that not mean that a participant's share is 0? If this is the case than a participant with a share of 0 instantly knows the secret is 0.

Am i missing something here?

And is this the correct way to post this or would I be better off leaving a comment on the post in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 0 in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. By the definition of a *group*, every element must have an inverse. Thus, the unity in a multiplicative group is 1 and there is no 0.

Comment: Ah i see, I misread the question and thought it was for a field. Thanks Yehuda